# ExtJS name is undefined error

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have `TypeError: name is undefined` in an ExtJS Application. It happens on the following line:

```
win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',cfg);
```

Where `cfg` is a long list of properties. It only happens in certain situations, I was wondering if anyone has any ideas as to how I can track down the cause of the error in `cfg`? Perhaps using Firebug or some other debugging tool.

Comment: when the error occurs you should be able to view the call stack and see where is it failing both with firebug and chrome dev tools...

Comment: `stack` was the keyword that got me on the right track, If you put this as an answer I'll mark it 'correct'.

Comment: @ArtF You should post what the error was, too.

Comment: @sra it was roughly what you described in your answer, one of my 'views' wasn't properly referenced in the controller, resulting the `xtype` not being in the `ClassManager`. I suspected that that is the issue when I posted the question but I wasn't sure, which is why I wanted to look at what was going on inside `cfg` more carefully.

Comment: You should ensure that any other user with a such a problem who stumbles over your question find a qualified answer. While looking at the stack points you in that direction still is not the solution. In such a case upvote and answer the question yourself. That help make stackoverflow better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the error occurs you should be able to view the call stack and see where is it failing both with firebug and chrome dev tools...

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It just asks for the call stack. -1

Comment: Actually it did answer the guy, because he found the answer by it (look at the comments on the question). The question was "how can I find the the solution to my problem?", and not "How to solve my problem?" I have pointed him to the right direction...

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely the error you face if a `xtype` or classname that cannot be found from the `ClassManager`. So you should check if you have a typo within the `cfg`